# ASP.NET MVC 5 classes to hold results of complex SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a webapp that uses a lot of stored procedures and whatnot in SQL Server, and as such I'll be executing a lot of raw SQL in my application.

I'm using code-first with automatic migrations, so I have a bunch of `WhateverModel` classes that, when I tell VS to do a migration, just sort of *work*, and end up in my database presto.

However, I want to create some classes that hold the results of my complex queries that I am running, and I do NOT want those to migrate, presto, into my database.  What is the correct paradigm for separating "These classes go as tables into my database" vs "These classes look like models, appear in my Context, but don't belong as tables in the database"?

Also, what would the appropriate location be for my raw SQL query that populates such a class? Should it be in the class itself (this is how I've done this in other languages), or in the context, or in the controller (this would preclude having them in my context, I think)?

Comment: I like to use the [Query Object Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html) to abstract the underlying query logic from the application layer (each query has it's own class with appropriate constructor parameters). Don't put query logic in controllers (can be considered an anti-pattern) because it ends up mixing several responsibilities in the UI layer.